# Localizing Static Text asp.net mvc3.What is the approach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Learning asp.net mvc and I am building a small website that will be initially in 2 languages.

10 or more pages are static pages with bold bits etc...

What is the best approach for localising these pages?

Is there a way to do it without creating a page for language that would be a no in my book.

How do you handle localisation of static pages in asp.net mvc? In asp.net there was some sort of localise control.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is using resource files. You create an resource file for your default language and then one for each other language your site should run in.

[This](http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2009/05/20/aspnet-mvc-globalizationlocalization.aspx) article describes how to do it. For example if you want english (default) and french you could create two resource files (.resx files) Website.resx and Website.fr-FR.resx. The first file for your default language, which is english and the second file for french. Both files exists from a key-value pair.

EDIT: Another interresting article describing the same idea can be found [here](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx).

Comment: THanks I like the idea or resource files.But still how do you handle the bold bits italics and so on that may be on the pages.I am localising the app using the resource files anyway but not sure what to do with static pages

Comment: Correct me if i understand you wrong but you could do this; <strong>@(Resources.MyKey)</strong>. Strong and italic are styling elements and belong on a page, not in a resource file even when the page is static.

Answer (score 0):

*I think that the best approach is still creating two files for them, 
cause they are not static pages forever, they may change in future,*

*Or you can generalize the solution and save the text in database 
for those two languages and render the correct content base on the selected culture.*

*They can be saved in the sense that they are pages on newsroom, 
whenever you add a news you enter the text for both cultures.*

Comment: Adding a page for each language will definitely work however it might become a maintenance nightmare.However with the database approach will work but how do you handle bold bits,italics here and there.Am I missing the obvious?

Comment: You can save the the rich text, moreover the rich text editors provide you the stripped text also.